# Kotlin: get List object from JSON string

Tags: android, json, kotlin

Exploring kotin possibilities at first time and a bit confused how to convert `JSON` string into `List` object.

data.json is quite simple

```
{
  "0" : "some picture",
  "1" : "other picture"
}
```

Trying to convert like this:

```
        val inputStream: InputStream = context?.assets?.open("data.json") ?: return null
    val size: Int = inputStream.available()
    val buffer = ByteArray(size)
    inputStream.read(buffer)
    val jsonString = String(buffer)

    println(jsonString)

    val gson = Gson()
    
    // THIS LINE CALLS ERROR
    val list: List<String> = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Array<String>::class.java).asList()

    list.forEachIndexed {index, item -> Log.i("item", "$index::$item")}
```

And getting error as result

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

How to fix this or how to correctly retrieve list object from json string?

Comment: The error is telling you what you need to know. You are telling Gson to expect an array (would be an array if enclosed in [ ] ) but your string is an object (enclosed in { } )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using List

```
val list: List<String> = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Array<String>::class.java).asList()
```

Use Map (This will parse your json data into map)

```
val map = gson.fromJson<Map<String, String>>(jsonString, MutableMap::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

This JSON isn't array. You have to make object fot this type. It will look like this:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class JsonData(
    @SerializedName("0")
    val x0: String,
    @SerializedName("1")
    val x1: String
)
```

Now in Your activity You can convert json to obbject:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.gson.Gson

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val gson = Gson()

        val json =
            """
            {
                "0" : "some picture",
                "1" : "other picture"
            }
            """

        val jsonData = gson.fromJson<JsonData>(json, JsonData::class.java)

        println(jsonData.x0) // some picture
        println(jsonData.x1) // other picture
    }
}
```

Now You can operate on that obcject but if You want list of string You can do  it like this:

```
val list = arrayListOf<String>(jsonData.x0, jsonData.x1)
println(list) //  [some picture, other picture]
```

Comment: what if he has more data in json like `"2": "Some more data", "2": "Some more data2"`

Comment: Then it won't work but I assumed that JSON only contains these two values. But if it really has many values this JSON should be just an array of  string

Comment: Thanks for reply. There could be more than two values, that's just an example.

Comment: Ohh, okay, so use the @akhilesh0707 answer, it should work well. But If it is Your JSON and every first value is just an index I think that You should make an array like this: `[  "some picture",  "other picture" ]`